# How to use Excel Functions IF and OR in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: validation

I am trying to use multiple nested IF() functions combined with the OR() function in SharePoint 2010. In Excel 2010 it works very well, but it is not working inside SharePoint. I already tried to use SharePoint Designer 2010 and InfoPath, but didn't work anyway.

The code sample used is:

```
=IF(OR(A2="Yes",B2="Yes",C2="Yes"),"OK",IF(OR(A2="No",B2="No",C2="No"),"Not OK","Action Pending"))
```

Thank you,

Rafael Vieira

Comment: Where are you adding this formula?

Comment: The logic of the formula is flawed or incomplete. If A2=yes, then the result is "OK", but if B2=No then what? Should it be "OK" as per the first IF() or "Not OK" as per the second IF()? Also, your code sample uses Excel style cell references. How does the formula look in your SharePoint setting? Are the columns called A2, B2, C2? Please provide a sample from SharePoint with column names and the formula as you use it in SharePoint. And please provide the context that you are using this formula in.

Comment: How are you trying to apply this formula? It should work fine as a calculated column provided you change the cell references to column references as Teylyn has suggested though I am a little puzzled by the references to SharePoint Designer and InfoPath?

Comment: Hi Teytyn, attached there the XLS file example with Formula working properly: http://www.sendspace.com/file/i12zk4  I have tried to apply it as conditional format and Formulas, but the expression IF is not found on that. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to use the Conditional Formats and apply Formulas, but I can't find the expression IF on that.